# How to partially stretch an image in a div with other images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a header for my website, which involves an image at the left and right of it, and a middle image that stretches sideways connecting both images at each side based on the width of the browser window. I have looked up how to do this, but all i can find it how to enlarge an image and how to stretch one image across the entire window. I also need to ensure that there is no whitespace between the images

```
<div id = "flag-header">
  <img src = "images/flag_header/flag_header_normal.png" height = "100px"></img
    ><img src = "images/flag_header/flag_header_middle.png" height = "100px" "max-width:100%"></img
  ><img src = "images/flag_header/flag_header_opposite.png" height = "100px"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use flexbox to remove the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

why do you do this `<img></img>` the img tag is a self closing tag you can use it like this
`<img src="" alt="">`
the simple solution is to use this

```css
.container {
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
height:300px;
width:99vw;
 border:1px solid blue /*I use this to show you that there is no white 
 space between the imgs you can delete this property */;
}
.border {
height:100px;
width:33vw;
background:green;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header class="container">
<img  class="border" src="#" alt="">
<img class="border" src="#" alt="">
<img class="border" src="#" alt="">
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

you can change width and height whatever you want ,you can use vw and vh instead of px to make it work the same on all browsers.also there is no white space between the 3images inside the header.you can change the width or height of images based on what you want on each image.

** if you only want to stretch the image in the div to fit the window size use this:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="img"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but i only want the middle image to stretch with the window, i would like the others to stay the same size

Comment: you can resize it what ever you want just give the img a class .if you want me to further help you just show me your code .

Comment: do you want to make an img as a background ? (stretch ) you can do that by making the middle img as a background and provide it with z-index:-1 property to make sur the 2 other imgs will show .if not the other images won't be seen properly

Comment: sorry could you tell me how to only stretch one image with view size?

Comment: check my solution I add it there when edit it it's down

Comment: the solution you need I add it   in the end of the answer check it